# PDO Select with Where Clause

Tags: sql, select, pdo, view

Hei, i've got error SQLSTATE 42000, can you help me.

I have 2 table and 1 view.

The first table is, Category Table

```
+--+--------+
|id|category|
+--+--------+
|1 |bird    |
|2 |fish    |
+--+--------+
```

Then i have animals table:

```
+--+---+-------+
|id|cat|animals|
+--+---+-------+
|1 |1  |Eagle  |
|2 |1  |Crow   |
|3 |2  |Shark  |
|4 |2  |Salmon |
+--+---+-------+
```

Then i create view to join the 2 table

```
+--+----+-------+
|id|cat |anm    |
+--+----+-------+
|1 |bird|Eagle  |
|2 |bird|Crow   |
|3 |fish|Shark  |
|4 |fish|Salmon |
+--+----+-------+
```

Then to show selected id from animal_view, i used this code:

```
<table>
<?php
$id=$_GET['id'];
$stmt=$db->prepare("SELECT * FROM animals_view WHERE id = $id");
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetchAll();
foreach($result as $data){
?>
<tr>
<td>Category:</td>
<td><?php echo $data['cat];?></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Animals:</td>
<td><?php echo $data['anm'];?></td>
</tr>
<?php }; ?>
</table>
```

Comment: You are missing a single quote here `$data['cat]`

Comment: But that won't throw the SQLSTATE error.

Comment: Can you post the actual error?